# Change iOS UIBarButtonItem Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

Is it possible to change the button type of a UIBarButton in iOS programmatically?

What I mean would be if you had a view with a navigation bar up the top and you have dragged on a UIBarButton which you have set to the "Compose" type so that it shows the icon of the pencil and paper, could you then drag an outlet of this to the view's ViewController and change the button to another type such as "Edit"?

Pseudo code, it might look like:

```
myBarButton.type = UIBarButtonType.Compose
```

Or something? Does such a functionality exist for **iOS 8 in Xcode with Swift 1.2**?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonSystemItem) you can only set that `UIBarButtonSystemItem` at initialization. There is no property for this.

Comment: @heikomania would it maybe be possible to remove the set button and replace it with a new button? Can we create new buttons and add to Nav bar on the fly in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can put a `UIButton` Instead of The `UIBarButtonItem` ! This is the only Way to get what you want.

The UIButton Can be Changed Easily and with anything you want !

Comment: Okay, so if I do that, what size do the picture images need to be to match the normal UIBarButtonItem image buttons? And I mean for 1x, @2x and 3x :)

Comment: I used a simple PNG icon with a resolution of 30x30 and it works fine

Comment: Apples official recommended size is 22x22 with respective `@2x` and `@3x`. https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/